# Cells cannot be copied from other worksheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm using python 3 on windows, and I'm trying to create a new worksheet on exciting excel file and then copy rows from the first sheet to the new one depending on specific cells value, but when I'm trying it I get this Error:
**"ValueError: Cells cannot be copied from other worksheets".**
Here is some of my code: (I'm importing load_workbook from openpyxl)

```
 def add_corrections(self):
    wb1 = load_workbook(self.path_to_save_use)
    wb1.create_sheet('תיקונים')
    columns = [('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'DZ')]
    for row in columns:
        wb1['תיקונים'].append(row)

    x = 0
    main_sheet = wb1['השוואת חתכים']
    for row in main_sheet.iter_rows():
        x = x + 1
        if x > 10:
            if row[9].value > self.limit:
                wb1['תיקונים'].append(row)
    wb1.save(self.path_to_save_use)
```

I have the x variable because I want to start looking from the 11th row

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are trying to append "row" object and not the value of that cell**

```python
wb1['תיקונים'].append(row)
```

**"row" is the tuple of cells
You have to convert that into list/tuple of values**

```python
x = 0
main_sheet = wb1['Sheet1']
for row in main_sheet.iter_rows():
    # HERE
    row_with_values = [cell.value for cell in row]
    # HERE
    x = x + 1
    if x > 10:
        if row[9].value > self.limit:
            wb1['תיקונים'].append(row_with_values)
    wb1['תיקונים'].append(row_with_values)
```

**It works for my test scenario, I hope it works for you too**

Comment: That's working thanks, but from some reason they skipped the first column when appended how do I fix this?, and is there a way to choose which cells in the row (by column) to append and not the entire row?

Comment: I guess you can remove unwanted cells from the list.
I highly suggest you to use different methods in general, try to fetch cells with range of columns.